# Set selected initial CupertinoPicker chosen index

Tags: flutter, cupertinopicker

I am new in Flutter development, I'm trying to `CupertinoPicker` inside `showCupertinoModalPopup` which triggered by clicking `CupertinoButton`.

After choosing the `Provinsi (Province)`, I can repick the `Province` by clicking again on the button, but It should be the item that I did choose.

Here's my code

```
showCupertinoModalPopup(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) {
    return new SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
    child: new CupertinoPicker(
      magnification: 1.2,
      useMagnifier: true,
      itemExtent: 32.0,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (i) => setState(() => _chosenProvince = listProvince[i]),
      children: r != null && listProvince != null ? listProvince.map((prov) {
      return new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: new Text(
        prov.name,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(): [],),);});
```

Is there any `initialValue` or something for `CupertinoPicker` to set to?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `FixedExtentScrollController` to set the **initialValue**. Refer to [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FixedExtentScrollController-class.html)

Comment: Super! Thank you.

Comment: I need on tap value how to achieve? Imagine user dont scroll and directly tap the value.

Comment: @stuckedoverflow you can return GestureDetector inside CupertinoPicker children

Comment: you mean initialItem?

Answer (score 32):

As described by Dinesh Balasubramanian you can use `FixedExtentScrollController` to set the `initialValue`

It will look like this, e.g. to start at the fourth element:

```
showCupertinoModalPopup(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) {
    return new SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
    child: new CupertinoPicker(
      scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 3),
      magnification: 1.2,
      useMagnifier: true,
      itemExtent: 32.0,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (i) => setState(() => _chosenProvince = listProvince[i]),
      children: r != null && listProvince != null ? listProvince.map((prov) {
      return new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: new Text(
        prov.name,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(): [],),);});
```